# Changing Height of Jframe using button

Tags: java, jframe

I want to change the height of my jFrame using a click of a button.

But I don't know where to start. I only have a button and don't know the code.

*EDIT : 
The code that I know can change the size of JFrame and move it's position to the top right corner is this

```
    Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(311, 430));
    Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(getPreferredSize());
    int wdwLeft = 530 + screenSize.width / 2 - windowSize.width / 2;
    int wdwTop = 0;
    pack();
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    setLocation(wdwLeft, wdwTop);
```

But I don't know specific code that can change the size of JFrame

*EDIT2 : Here's my `public static void main(String args[])`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final VoucherChecker frame = new VoucherChecker();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know how to call `frame` to use at `frame.setSize`

Comment: where is your tested codes?

Comment: I don't have any code to test. But I only know that I can change the height of jframe in the init section... I will update the question

Comment: That's the code that I know can change the size of JFrame. But It's only work on init @Sachith

Comment: @MArgus, What is `init`? Is a method called in your constructor? If you post a [mcve], it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry @Gulllie. Yes, I mean `init`. Method that called in my constructor.. I'm sorry this question is not provide any info of the code, because I don't know what code that I need to provide.. I know the code on that question is from another question and it's for moving position of the JFrame and  resize the JFrame..

Comment: Ok, so you what to know how to make that code run when a button is clicked (and so resize your `JFrame`)?

Comment: Yes.That's my objective @Gulllie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run code when a button is pressed, add an [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the button with the `.addActionListener()` method. Have a look at this code here, and see if that works for you: (*Read the comments to see what's going on*)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();                                 //Create a Main object, wrapped by SwingUtilities.invokeLater to make it thread safe
            }
        });

    }

    public Main() {                                         //Main's constructor

        frame = new JFrame();                               //Create JFrame
        frame.setTitle("Test Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        init((JPanel)frame.getContentPane());               //'init' frame's JPanel
        setFrameSizeAndPos(frame);                          //Set the frame's size

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setFrameSizeAndPos(JFrame frame) {

        //Set JFrame size here! Eg:
        frame.pack();                                       //Set the frame size, you could change this to set it in a different way.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                  //Place frame in the center of the screen
    }

    private void init(JPanel panel) {
        //Setup your GUI here...
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");         //Create button
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){     //add an ActionListener to the button, passing in an Anonymous Class

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setFrameSizeAndPos(frame);                  //This will be called then the button is pressed
            }
        });

        panel.add(button1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for give this code `private static JFrame frame;`.. I'm using NetBeans and I think they provide me with `private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` so I'm not have to `addActionListener` on it (It already provide by the NetBeans). Because that code, I can use the `frame` variable on my `jButton3ActionPerformed`

Comment: @MArgus Happy to help. :) Don't forget to mark a question as answered when your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the frame size on a button click then you can try this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Stackoverflow");


        JButton button = new JButton("Change Size");
        button.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /* now you can do some calculation that
                how much you want to change
                the frame size by the button click */

                // increasing hight by 50
                frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 50); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a little problem.. Might be something with my code.. Please see the updated question. I will include my `public void run()`

Comment: Why are you suggesting to a newbie to add a MouseListener to a JButton? If the JButton is disabled, will pressing it result in an action? Should it? -1 for giving bad example and advice.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for provide the `setSize` information. I'm using NetBeans, so I think NetBeans will provide me a function `private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` and I put the `setSize` code on it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels edited the answer, removed the MouseListener.

Comment: @MArgusChopinGyver sorry, I didn't noticed the edit earlier.